# How many days later does the UK embassy share refusal information with other countries?

Tags: usa, uk, canada, visa-refusals

Recently I was refused by the UK. Now I want to apply for a Canadian visit visa.

My question is, how many days later does the UK embassy share the refusal information with other countries?

Comment: Are you hoping to get a Canadian visa approved before they find out about the UK refusal? Don't do this. If the Canadians find out about a refusal that you haven't declared you can forget about going to Canada for a very long time. Be honest. You'll get a visa, or you won't, but you won't get a long ban for deception.

Comment: So you had a good reason to visit the UK, with documentation to prove it, and now you have a good reason to visit Canada, with documentation to prove it? You would be better off trying to address the issues raised by the UK ECO (or realise that you can’t, and there’s no reason Canada will come to a different conclusion).

Comment: Assume it is question of hours. I do not think UK will send the data to Canada at every refusal, but that they share some system about passports, visa, crimes, and possibly other stuffs, so information is instantaneous, and I assume you may be already on the system by requesting a visa (so as pending, so they may see you as visa shopper). I do not think they will give much information, but just a "flag". Then (I assume) manual interaction, but who know? it is not public, so we can only guess. Stay on safe side.

Comment: Even if you are issued a Canadian visa before they get wind of your UK refusal - you should be aware that a visa is not a "right to enter". If the Canadian authorities receive additional information about you subsequent to issuing you a visa they can always send you back home when you arrive in Canada.

Answer (score 5):

That information is not public knowledge.

However, if you are trying to lie in the Canada application saying that you didn't get a visa refusal and they find out, then you will be held liable for deception, which may include a ban.

So, see what was wrong with the application, rectify the things you can and be truthful about refusal.